# Unable to access a particular URL from AWS EC2 Instance

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, dns

API URL: https://abhasbx.abdm.gov.in/abha/api/v3/enrollment/request/otp

I'm able to access above URL in browser, postman & from Node.js server in my local but when i'm trying to do same thing in my EC2 Server its not reachable and throws "Error: connect ETIMEDOUT" Error. Im able to access all other APIs and sites in my EC2 Server

Please help me on this

thanks

I tried to consume below api from EC2 server but its not responding.
API URL: https://abhasbx.abdm.gov.in/abha/api/v3/enrollment/request/otp

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to check inbound and outbound rules for your ec2 instance.
check whether you have map your elastic ip with your ec2 or not.
you need to configure your nginx accordingly.

it may be a problem with your Nginx

Answer (score 0):

Check your networking in AWS, there is possibilities that it's blocked from your environment : Security Groups, firewalls, etc . But it's also possible that for some reasons the website is blocking AWS IP ranges.

You could try the VPC Reachability Analyzer if you need help to figure out why.